# jQuery show hidden content, then auto scroll to the middle of the content

Tags: jquery, scroll, show-hide

I have a button set up that when clicked, expands the page. Here is the code:

```
/*Source:http://rpardz.com/blog/show-hide-content-jquery-tutorial*/

jQuery('.open-content').hide().before('<div class="container_12"><a href="#" id="toggle-content" class="button"><div id="expand-button" ></div></a></div><div id="toggle-top" style="width:100%"></div>');
jQuery('a#toggle-content').click(function() {
    jQuery('.open-content').slideToggle(1000);
    return false;
});
```

It works nicely as you can see: Hidden: http://cl.ly/101v0N0W1z2D2e0x3a0j Expanded: http://cl.ly/1Z2Q1d3Y2z2X3G1j1v2G

Notice (see the scroll on the side of the images) how the bottom of page expands to show more content; what I can't figure out is how to make the page auto scroll to the bottom of the now visible content after the page finishes expanding..

I use this standard script to smooth scroll to places on the page..

```
/*Source: http://goo.gl/DaRfF */
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$(".scroll").click(function(event){     
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
});
```

});

but I cannot see how to integrate this so that it automatically scrolls to the bottom of the content after it finishes expanding. All help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about something like this?

```
jQuery('.open-content').slideToggle(1000, function(){
   var offset = jQuery('.open-content').offset();
   var y = offset.top + jQuery('.open-content').height();
   var wheight = $(window).height()
   var scroll = y - wheight;
   $(document).animate({scrollTop:scroll}, 500);
});
```

Comment: Fantastic! This is very close; the only issue I am having with the above is that upon click it shoots me to the top of the page before scrolling down to the new expanded page area. How can I prevent it from linking to the top before it scrolls down to view the expanded area?  Maybe it is that I have implemented it incorrectly: https://gist.github.com/1129878

Comment: I am also noticing that if I zoom completely out so the current position of page is equivalent to the top of the page, clicking the expand button shifts the entire page to the left by about ten pixels. Makes the effect look a little jerky.

Comment: I change the selector to `document` (should work better now).
Also, I recommend you use the [scrollTo plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html), code will be something like this: `$(document).scrollTo({top: scroll}, 'medium');`

Comment: Great tip. The issue of it linking to the top was a rogue href="#" x-D. Fantastic help, CM; thanks!